# Not able to install plugins in latest openmdao 1.7.x

Tags: openmdao

I am interested in multiobjective optimization using genetic algorithm or particle swam. For this I understood, that I need to install the pyopt plugin.

Though it seems that the driver listed here:
https://github.com/OpenMDAO-Plugins?page=1
are not suitable for the latest release. Is this right?
Is there another repository for the current drivers?

I am also not sure how to install the drivers as the 'plugin' command is not in my path and I did not find it when I dowloaded the git repository.

Could you point me to an multiobjective nsga tutorial?
In addition to this I am interested in the dakota-plugin in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugins page you've referenced is for an Older version of OpenMDAO (V 0.0.13 and older). For 1.7.x, we handle plugins a bit differently. OpenMDAO is now a standard python package and any plugins can just list it as a dependency.

That being said, you don't actually need a plugin for pyopt_sparse. The wrapper for it is built into OpenMDAO. You just need to install pyopt_sparse from [it's bitbucket repo](https://bitbucket.org/mdolab/pyoptsparse). After that you can just use it.

You can see an example of setting  up pyopt_sparse in the OpenMDAO tests suite [here.](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/cfaefda8b24e3c21a858c775378f72097e3dc328/openmdao/drivers/test/test_pyoptsparse.py)

Comment: Ok, after the installation I got:

Comment: the error: 'There was an error importing the compiled snopt module' and the same for 'slsqp'.

Comment: I assume the other drivers like e.g. dakota do not exist yet for 1.7.x. Is this right?

Comment: It sounds like your pyopt_sparse install didn't work right. correct, the dakota driver hasn't yet been updated for 1.7.x

Comment: Yes, I will check this further. Thanks!